# Serializing object methods with Pickle

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the `pickle` module.

It seems to me that `pickle` doesn't save methods, only attributes.

Here is what I mean with a code:

```
import pickle

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def add_dot(self):
        self.name += '.'

etienne = Person('etienne')
pickled = pickle.dumps(etienne)

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def add_dot(self):
        self.name += '..' 

etienne = pickle.loads(pickled)
etienne.add_dot()
```

What would you expect this code to return?

Is someone able to explain me this behaviour?

Comment: What `pickle` actually saved was that there is an instance of a class named `Person`, defined in the module named `__main__`, containing an attribute `name` with a certain value.  When you unpickled that data, the current version of `__main__.Person` was used, which isn't the same version of the class.  If `pickle` didn't work that way, it would be impossible to fix bugs or add features to your code, as the pickled data would be stuck with the original definitions forever.

Comment: @jasonharper That was exactly the answer I was expecting, ty. Post it if you want, I will validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot pickle methods but you can pickle ***functions (built-in and user-defined) accessible from the top level of a module (using def, not lambda).***

[The Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) states the types that can be pickled and unpickled are:

> - None, True, and False;
> - integers, floating-point numbers, complex numbers;
> - strings, bytes, bytearrays;
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects;
> - **functions (built-in and user-defined) accessible from the top level of a module (using def, not lambda);**
> - classes accessible from the top level of a module;
> - instances of such classes whose __dict__ or the result of calling __getstate__() is picklable (see section Pickling Class Instances for details).

As per [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), **serialization** is:

> the process of translating a **data structure** or **object state** into a
> format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory data
> buffer) or transmitted (for example, over a computer network) and
> reconstructed later (possibly in a different computer environment).

The Pickle module simply wasn't built to serialize methods. The main purpose is to serialize **state**, the state of the attributes. The object is then instantiated when unpickling. As the method is part of the class definition, your code works fine but only with the later definition of the class. Thus `etienne.name` value end up being *"etienne.."*.

In the context of an instance, saving the class definition also is usually inadequate and undesirable as instructions on how to use the serialized data may change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it? Adding the line `print(etienne.name)` and running it returns "etienne..", but the better question is *why?*

The important thing to remember when pickling a class instance is that a class instance is really made up of two things: the instance variables (call `myClass.__dict__` to see what those look like) and the source code that tells python how you want those data interpreted. When you call a method on an *instance* of a class (like `etienne.add_dot()`), it gets translated into a basic function call to the method in the class, while passing in the instance as the argument for `self` (so `etienne.add_dot()` becomes `Person(etienne)`). This scheme is widely used for OOP, as it helps save loads of space when you are running programs with a lot of instances of a class, since each one can just store the instance variables and refer to the same source code when they have a method called on them.

As you have noticed, the `pickle` module uses the same exact scheme when pickling classes, only saving instance variables and not the source code for the class itself. From the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-inst):

> This is done on purpose, so you can fix bugs in a class or add methods to the class and still load objects that were created with an earlier version of the class.